# Changing text in html with Golang without affecting html tags

Tags: html, go, text

Here is an HTML code:

```
<h2>Relative URLs</h2>
<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML Images</a></p>
<p><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a></p>
```

How can I replace, change case or do something with text without affecting any html tags using Golang? For example:

```
<h2>RELATIVE URLS</h2>
<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML IMAGES</a></p>
<p><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS TUTORIAL</a></p>
```

Comment: Please include what you tried

Comment: Use [`golang.org/x/net/html`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html).

Comment: I am new in go.... Can you show me please more detailed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some xpath based parser like [htmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/htmlquery)

```golang
s := `<html><head></head><body><h2>Relative URLs</h2>
<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML Images</a></p></body></html>`

doc, _ := htmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
fmt.Printf("Before update \n%s\n", htmlquery.OutputHTML(doc, true))

nodes := htmlquery.Find(doc, "/html/body//*")

for _, node := range nodes {
  if node.FirstChild.DataAtom == 0 { 
    // DataAtom is the atom for Data, or zero if Data is not a known tag name.
    node.FirstChild.Data = strings.ToUpper(node.FirstChild.Data)
  }
}
fmt.Printf("After update \n%s\n", htmlquery.OutputHTML(doc, true))
```

**Output**

```html
Before update 
<html><head></head><body><h2>Relative URLs</h2>
<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML Images</a></p></body></html>
After update 
<html><head></head><body><h2>RELATIVE URLS</h2>
<p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML IMAGES</a></p></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank  you very much for your example! But as you see Relative URLs is still not in upper case.... How to fix that ALL text will be upper case besides tags?

Comment: With this code: node := htmlquery.FindOne(doc, "/html/body/*") changes only Relative URLs ...

Comment: @Seomat need to use `"/html/body//*"` for all nodes in the body and  `htmlQuery.Find` that returns list of matched nodes, all in this case. Update can be done based on the  DataAtom of the node.

Comment: @Seomat, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it (click the ✔️  near the top left of the answer)

Comment: Of course, already made!

Comment: One question: when there are these tags - title, script, then i got error: 

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x2c pc=0x773bad]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        main.go:1627 +0x1ed
exit status 2

Is there is a solution to avoid this error? Thanks!

Comment: check `node.FirstChild` for `nil` in the loop